# Command dispatcher in Python

Tags: python

I have this function in python:

```py
def executecommand(call):
    if call.data == "/getpair":
        return getpaircmd(call.message)
    elif call.data == "/menu":
        return menucmd(call.message)
    elif call.data == "/setalarm":
        return setalarmcmd(call.message)
```

And I was hoping to replace it with object and `.get(call.data)` message, like this:

> ```py
> def executecommand(call):
>     return {
>         "/getpair": getpaircmd(call.message),
>         "/menu": menucmd(call.message),
>         "/setalarm": setalarmcmd(call.message)
>     }.get(call.data)
> ```

But it seems like it calls every function on the list.

So, is there a way to simplify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses act as a function-calling operator in Python. Therefore, your attempt to build the dispatch table would end up calling all the functions. What you can do instead is this:

```
def executecommand(call):
    return {
        "/getpair": getpaircmd,
        "/menu": menucmd,
        "/setalarm": setalarmcmd,
    }[call.data](call.message)
```

Note that the behavior with the lookup table is different from the original in the case where `call.data` is not one of the expected choices. In your code unknown messages will be ignored, in the example code above it would raise a `TypeError` because the dictionary would return `None`, which is not callable.

I also recommend putting a comma consistently, so that if you later add or remove a command, you'll get cleaner diffs in your source code version control.

The fact that you see all the functions being called highlights a potential performance issue: the dispatch table is rebuilt every time `executecommand()` runs. The table should be built just once:

```
_DISPATCH = {
    "/getpair": getpaircmd,
    "/menu": menucmd,
    "/setalarm": setalarmcmd,
}

def executecommand(call):
    return _DISPATCH[call.data](call.message)
```